# Accidentally delete Web Application in Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint, web-applications

I've just accidentally deleted a Web application from Central Administration in my SharePoint 2007 server farm using "Delete Web application". I've chose both "No" to "Delete content databases" and "Delete IIS Website". So, I've still had the contents of the virtual directory and content database.

I've tried a few things here but it is not working.

first, i tried to restore the content database of "Central Administration website" to earlier date, but the settings are not reverted.

Then I tried to create a new web application under same port number "e.g 8000" and then create an empty site collection on it. Then I tried to add the content database of the original website. it shows the content db contains '0' site collection.

Is there any suggestion what i should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, backup the original content database to a safe location to ensure you have a good copy of it somewhere. Here is the basic procedure after which I provide the detailed steps.

**BASIC PROCEDURE**
Backup the existing content database for safety
Delete the current site, keeping the content database
Recreate the site with a new content database
Detach the new content database
Attach the old content database

**DETAILED STEPS**

1. Delete everything for the site **except the original content database**. This includes the IIS Site and any new content databases you created. You should have a fresh slate now to work with.
2. Recreate the site with the exact same settings but **use a unique name for the new content database**. For example, use the same URL, Port, etc. but if your original content database was called myspcontentdb use the name myspcontentdb-new for the new content database.
3. Once the new site is created, verify you can access it in a browser.
4. Open SharePoint Central Administration
5. On the top navigation bar, click Application Management.
6. On the Application Management page, in the SharePoint Web Application Management section, click Content databases.
7. On the Manage Content Databases page, click the **NEW** content database (myspcontentdb-new).
8. On the Manage Content Database Settings page, in the Remove Content Database section, select the Remove content database check box.
9. Click OK to indicate that you want to proceed with the removal.
10. Click OK again.
11. On the Manage Content Databases page, click Add a content database.
12. Ensure the correct Web Application is selected.
13. In the Database Name and Authentication section, in the Database Server box, type the name of the database server.
14. In the Database Name box, type a name for the **ORIGINAL** content database (myspcontentdb).
15. Select the appropriate database authentication
16. Complete the rest of the form then click OK.
17. Verify the site works with the new content database.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262440(v=office.12).aspx